# setTextSize(++size) increases font size a lot not just a little

Tags: android, font-size, increment

I am trying to implement a button that will increase the font size of text in `TextView` I have came up with the following :

```
  Button biggerFont;
  TextView centerTextView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    biggerFont =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bigger_font);
    centerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_center);

    biggerFont.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        float tempSize = centerTextView.getTextSize();
        Log.d(USER_SERVICE, Float.toString(tempSize));
        centerTextView.setTextSize(++tempSize);
      }
    });
    // ...
  }
```

But this will increase the font size a lot! each time I click the button. On logging I have check and `tempSize` increases not by 1 but irregularly (44->90->182).

I have also tried using

```
    float tempSize = centerTextView.getTextSize() + 1;
```

but the same thing.

Comment: `getTextSize()`: the size (in pixels) of the default text size in this TextView. - try `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, ++tempSize);`

Comment: @MarcoAcierno This works. :) You can post it as an answer.

Comment: :) ok posted as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getTextSize()
```

> the size (in pixels) of the default text size in this TextView.

use

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, ++tempSize);
```

`setTextSize` uses `scaled pixel` by default (`setTextSize(int)`), with `setTextSize(int, int)` you say the unit to use.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `setTextSize(float size)`. According to the documentation, this sets the text size in *scaled pixel* units.

But then `getTextSize()` returns it back to you in *pixel* units, not *scaled pixel* units.

So the solution is to call the other `setTextSize` method that allows you to explicitly set the unit type.

Here's a stackoverflow question about the differences in units:

> [What's the relationship between pixels and scaled pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000892/whats-the-relationship-between-pixels-and-scaled-pixels)

Answer (score 0):

```
void setTextSize(int unit, float size) :
```

Sets the default text size to a given unit and value